# how should I use the right owner task in airflow?

Tags: owner, airflow

I dont understand the "owner" in airflow. the comment of ower is "the owner of the task, using the unix username is recommended".
I wrote some the following code.

```
   Default_args = {
'owner': 'max',
'depends_on_past': False,
'start_date': datetime(2016, 7, 14),
'email': ['max@test.com'],
'email_on_failure': False,
'email_on_retry': False,
'retries': 1,
'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
```

}

```
dag = DAG('dmp-annalect', default_args=default_args,
                schedule_interval='30 0 * * *')

pigjob_basedata = """{local_dir}/src/basedata/basedata.sh > 
{local_dir}/log/basedata/run_log &
""".format(local_dir=WORKSPACE)

task1_pigjob_basedata = BashOperator(
task_id='task1_pigjob_basedata',owner='max',
bash_command=pigjob_basedata ,
dag=dag)
```

But I used the command "airflow test dagid taskid 2016-07-20" , I got some error,
...
 {bash_operator.py:77} INFO - put: Permission denied: user=airflow, 
....

I thought that my job ran with "max" user, but apperently , ran test using 'airflow' user .

I hope if I run my task using 'max' user, how should I do.

Answer (score 4):

I figured out this issue.
Because I set the AIRFLOW_HOME in /home/airflow/,  only airflow can access this file directory.

Comment: Hello Max, thanks for your investigation, I was having a hard time figuring it out as well. Currently it feels not very intuitive. Since I am working with docker and mapped the folder of airflow into a local folder it overwrote the folder with root permissions. Your question guided me into the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

I've mitigated this by adding user `airflow` and all other users who own tasks into a group, then giving the entire group permission to read, write and execute files within `airflow`'s home. Not sure if this is best practice, but it works and makes the `owner` field more useful than setting `airflow` as the `owner` of every DAG.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the list of dags in webserver by `owner` name when authentication is turned on by setting webserver:filter_by_owner in your config. With this, a user will see only the dags which it is owner of, unless it is a superuser.

```
[webserver]
filter_by_owner = True
```