# What is the 'owner' property in Airflow used for?

Tags: airflow

I cannot find any information on what the `owner` variable is used for in the docs. The only mention of `owner` I found was in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38520458/how-should-i-use-the-right-owner-task-in-airflow) Stack Overflow question and in the [Security section](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.2/security.html?highlight=owner) of the docs, both of which don't help in understanding the general concept.

Comment: when you need to blame someone for this DAG, you can find out the owner is a good source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I see in the Airflow repository, it's just information. It's shown
as a column in the main DAG view in Airflow, and if you click on that name it will show you all the DAGs from that owner (at least in Airflow 2).

Answer (score 2):

The origins of owner lie in legacy airflow (v1).
Basically it was used to denote the user in the linux machine. Then in the pre-RBAC days it could be used to restrict access to dags running only for those owners.

Now that only RBAC is there through user signups, there is no need for owner fields. It only serves a cosmetic purpose (albeit an important one) of identifying the DAG owner